# How to override symfony2 hover message in form?

Tags: symfony

I've create a symfony2 form, and I want to override the hover message (when you put your mouse on the input). There is a message like this "Please fill out this field".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is HTML5 validation

check the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-html5-validation-disable

> The client-side validation, however, can be disabled by adding the novalidate attribute to the form tag or formnovalidate to the submit tag.